# SQL: list of points to rectangle

Tags: sql, points, regions

I have two tables:

```
regions <id>
points <region_id, x, y>
```

*Assuming* there are exactly 4 points per region, and these points describe a rectangle -- is there an SQL query that will bring me this view:

```
rectangular_regions <region_id, x1, y1, x2, y2>
```

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT region_id, MIN(x) AS x1, MIN(y) AS y1, MAX(x) AS x2, MAX(y) AS y2 
FROM points 
GROUP BY region_id.
```